# INSERT XML into SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xmltextwriter

Hello I'm trying to insert some XML data into a table on SQL Server 2008.  However I keep getting thrown this error;

> XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

The database column filemeta uses the XML datatype, and I've switch the encoding to UTF-16 which I believe is necessary for adding XML data.

```
INSERT INTO testfiles
  (filename, filemeta) 
VALUES 
  ('test.mp3', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?><!--This is a test XML file--><filemeta filetype="Audio"><Comments /><AlbumTitle /><TrackNumber /><ArtistName /><Year /><Genre /><TrackTitle /></filemeta>');
```

Help, I'm stuck.

NB: I created the XML with XMLTextWriter.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, there are issues when you try to insert XML into SQL Server 2008 and the XML contains an encoding instruction line.

I typically get around using the `CONVERT` function which allows me to instruct SQL Server to skip those instructions - use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO testfiles
  (filename, filemeta) 
VALUES 
  ('test.mp3', CONVERT(XML, N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>......', 2));
```

It has definitely helped me get various encoded XML stuff into SQL Server.

See the [MSDN docs on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - a bit down the page there's a number of styles you can use for `CONVERT` with `XML` and some explanations about them.

Comment: +1 this is probably the trickiest error in whole SQL XML story: mixing explicit encoding declarations with implicit encoding derived form the string type (ASCII or Unicode). No mortal stands any chance against this one...

Answer (score 21):

You just need to include **N** in front of your XML string to make it unicode.

```
INSERT INTO testfiles
  (filename, filemeta) 
VALUES 
  ('test.mp3', N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?><!--This is a test XML file--><filemeta filetype="Audio"><Comments /><AlbumTitle /><TrackNumber /><ArtistName /><Year /><Genre /><TrackTitle /></filemeta>');
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me without any errors:

```
DECLARE @input XML 
SET @input = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?><!--This is a test XML file--><filemeta filetype="Audio"><Comments /><AlbumTitle /><TrackNumber /><ArtistName /><Year /><Genre /><TrackTitle /></filemeta>'

INSERT INTO testfiles (filename, filemeta)
VALUES ('test.mp3', @input);
```