# Getting syntax error while inserting string of XML data in column of data type LongText

Tags: mysql, xml

I am using the My SQL Server 5.0 and My SQL Query Browser 1.1

```
     INSERT INTO `service_settings` (`service_id`,`settings`) VALUES
 (17,'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n<SecurityDataRepository>\r\n <SecurityPriceSheet>        \r\n        <first50Pages>1</first50Pages>\r\n      <additionalPages>0.5</additionalPages>\r\n      <staasLitePrice>500</staasLitePrice>\r\n        <serviceUnitPrice>600</serviceUnitPrice>\r\n        <toolUnitPrice>1200</toolUnitPrice>\r\n </SecurityPriceSheet>\r\n</SecurityDataRepository>');
```

I am getting a syntax error( `Error No. 1064`) while inserting the String in column of datatype `LONGTEXT`
I have gone through previous threads [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628846/insert-xml-into-sql-server-2008-database) but it did not work for me .

Comment: can't reproduce, insert is fine for me...

Comment: is there any solution to this